# WW2 - Translate German text

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany

I recently visited my friend in Guernsey and explored a German gun placement in his garden. 
On the walls there was writing and I am curious if anyone is able to translate it. Unfortunately a lot of the text is faded - but any clues on what it could say would be awesome

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "*Belueftung*" = ventilation

Comment: "*alle Schieber schliessen*" = close all slides

Comment: I can't read enough of anything else to enter it into Google translate.

Comment: Before "alle Schieber schliessen" is most likely the word "Gefahr". I can't make out the second to last word in that picture, but it looks like it ends in -öpfe. Maybe schöpfe? "Andrehen" is "turn on".

Comment: Andrehen suggest "knoepfe", knobs/taps

Comment: Are you sure it was a gun deposit? Why would it need ventilation controls?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro This was one of the Mirus gun emplacements - so it's a vast underground structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Picture 1:
  *Belüftung*
  -– ventilation
- Picture 2:
  [Bei] *Gefahr alle Schieber schließen – Knöpfe andrehen*
  –– In a dangerous situation: close all sliders – ([start to] turn)/(fasten) all buttons
- Picture 3:
  *B[ei] künstlicher Belüftung – Hebel nach oben*
  –– If/When operating/under artificial ventilation  – lever to the top
- Picture 4:
  *...............  die Schieber schließen* (Maybe *Gefahr alle* ?)
  –– close the sliders  (When in danger close all sliders)
  (too bad, or worse, to make out anything at the start. Maybe with a better picture? There *is* a second line.)

Comment: On my next visit I will try to get a few better pictures and explore a bit more.
I imagine the text in 2nd and 4th pictures are saying the same thing.
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Try finding other gun emplacements when you visit again - the writing may be in better condition...

Comment: Being German I confirm that all readings and translations are correct, the last one is simply too faded to make it out.